# How to open a excel file/Log file through CAPL for viewing

Tags: excel, capl, canoe

Whenever the CAPL script is executed, I want to open an excel file or log file.
For example, there is a file named " Standard_details.xlsx or Logfile.txt". once the CAPL script is executed, I need this file to be opened for the user to read. How to open .xlsx or .txt file through CAPL script?

Answer (score 2):

CAPL has function `sysExec` and `sysExecCmd`, which allow you to run external commands.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you, to use a parser for that file and import in a matrix.
This is my personal solution to parse a CSV file :

```html
void loadSimpleCCSfile (char ccsFile [], long matrix [][]){
  dword fh;
    char text[1000],temp[1000];
    int CCS_index,i,res,lastRes;

    fh = openFileRead(ccsFile,0);
    if (!fh) {
        write ("ERROR CCS: Open file failed!");
        return;
    }else{
        write("Open file %s",ccsFile);
    }
    write("Parsing file %s...",ccsFile);
  
    /* read first line and check */
    if (!fileGetString(text, elcount(text), fh) || strstr(text, "UCM#") < 0) {      
        write("ERROR: Wrong file format, 'UCM#' not found!");   
    }
    CCS_index = 0;
    while(fileGetString(text, elcount(text), fh))
    { 
        lastRes = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < elcount(matrix[0]); i++)
        {
            res = strstr_off(text, lastRes, ";");
            substr_cpy_off(temp, 0, text, lastRes, res-lastRes, 40);
            strtol(temp, matrix[CCS_index][i]);
            lastRes = res+1;
        }
      //write("%d -> %s",CCS_index,text);
        CCS_index = CCS_index + 1;
    } 
    write("%d Elements",CCS_index);
    fileClose(fh);
}
```